# Single hyperlink pointing to multiple bookmarks/headings in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

After submitting hundreds of resumes to job postings, I figured out that my old-school, bullet point CV-s have probably been never read.

To make life easier for headhunters, I plan to insert a short summary in front of my detailed resume which includes only certain key words (like: consolidation, IFRS reporting etc) in the form of hyperlinks.

My problem is that these key words appear many times in my CV at different places and I want the headhunters to see **all** of my previous workplaces where I did consolidation by **clicking** only **once** on a hyperlink.

Unfortunately, one hyperlink may only point to one bookmark in my CV, instead of "jumping" from one bookmark to another.

My guess is that the above task can be solved only with VBA scripting, which I am not really familiar.

Anyone has any idea?

[image: part of my CV, multiple bookmarks]

Comment: Note recruiters don't read CVs, they just keyword match ... I have lots of experience with this, with recruiters sending me unsuitable jobs because of a keyword match that if you actually read the CV isn't really a match.

Comment: Hi David, I have the same feeling as to how the recruiters work. Close to being 50, the situation gets even worse because when they realize that you are more than 30, your application won't even hit their search engine. This is very sad, I have several qualifications (mostly accounting and economics), 20+ years of professional (and managerial) experience, and now I work as an accounting assistant (!).

Comment: I have the same problem, only worse. I'm 57 and have been looking for a job for nearly 4 years :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. A separate page in the document for each of the terms you want to highlight, so if the reader wants to know more about e.g. your consolidation experience, it's all right there.  That satisfies the one-click requirement.
   At the end of that section, include a link back to the page the original link is on so the reader can easily return.
2. At the end of each section that gives examples of your consolidation experience, include a link to the next section that gives another example; ex:  "See also Gabor's consolidation experience at XYZ, Inc."

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I guess that I go for the 2nd option. Every key word will in itself be another hyperlink pointing to the next key word, which is, again, another hyperlink. This way, every one who reads my CV may jump through the interesting sections quickly, and leave out the less relevant ones. I guess I became a bit "rusty" :-) over time because your approach is very logical.